# Dynamically set curl path via environment variable in puppet 3.7.4 returns "Could not find command ''"

Tags: curl, environment-variables, exec, puppet, redhat

Some of our instances are running on older operating systems that have a different location for the curl command than others which was resulting on a failed puppet run on those nodes due to a "curl: command not found" error.

We then tried setting the `command` => `export $curl_path=$(which curl) && $curl_path -sS -o ${service_to_install} https://service_to_install.parent.com/service_to_install || rm -f ${service_to_install}"`

but were met with puppet failures due to `export: command not found` I found another post that suggested setting that curl_path variable using `environment =>` like below:

```
  $service_to_install = '/root/service_to_install'
  
  exec { 'service_to_install_placeholder':
    command => "/bin/echo Unauthorized > ${service_to_install)}",
    creates => $service_to_install,
  }
  # Download the installer.
  exec { 'fetch_service_to_install' :
    environment => ["curl_path=$(which curl)"],
    command => "$curl_path -sS -o ${service_to_install} https://service_to_install.parent.com/service_to_install || rm -f ${service_to_install}",
    path    => [ '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin' ],
    timeout => 600,
    onlyif  => "/bin/grep -q Unauthorized ${service_to_install}",
  }
  # then we run the installer
  exec { 'agent_install' :
    command => "bash ${service_to_install} ",
    path    => [ '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin' ],
    timeout => 600,
    require => Exec['fetch_service_to_install'],
  }
```

But this results in `/Stage[main]/Jumpcloud_login/Exec[fetch_service_to_install]/returns` `Could not find command ''`

How do we dynamically set curl using the which curl command here?

In case it matters, the system we're seeing the error on is Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03 RedHat.

Comment: The error message implies `which curl` returns an empty string.

Comment: Yes that's apparent, but when I get on to the host, `which curl` returns `/usr/bin/curl`

Comment: Since `which` is not a command, you can try `sh -c 'which curl'`.

Comment: I changed that line to `environment => ["curl_path=$(sh -c 'which curl')"],` which resulted in the same error `/Stage[main]/Jumpcloud_login/Exec[fetch_kickstart]/returns` `change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not find command ''`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect use-case for Hiera matching on `facts.os.name` and `facts.os.release.major` (and similar). You could imagine your top level `hiera.yaml` looking something like:

```yaml
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: 'os-specific data'
    path: 'os/%{facts.os.name}-%{facts.os.release.major}.yaml'
  - name: 'common data'
    path: 'common.yaml'
```

And then from there you use a variable called `my_module::curl_path` that might default to `/usr/bin/curl` in `common.yaml` and otherwise overridden for your older/different machines.

At that point your code becomes something like:

```
curl_path = lookup('my_module::curl_path', String)

exec { 'fetch_service_to_install' :
  command => "${curl_path} -sS -o ${service_to_install} https://service_to_install.parent.com/service_to_install || rm -f ${service_to_install}",
  path    => [ '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin' ],
  timeout => 600,
  onlyif  => "/bin/grep -q Unauthorized ${service_to_install}",
}
```

(probably best to make it a manifest/module parameter, so that `lookup()` isn't necessary).

Comment: I should mention that I forgot you are working with Puppet 3.7, which would require a different setup than above.